# ui:inputDate and placeholder issue in nested component

Tags: lightning, inputdate

I have `<ui:inputDate>` field for which I set the `placeholder` via JS, like so:

**INPUTDATE.cmp:**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ui:inputDate aura:id="inputDate" displayDatePicker="true" />
    <ui:button press="{!c.setPlaceholder}" label="Set placeholder" />
</aura:component>
```

**JS CONTROLLER:**

```
({
    setPlaceholder : function(component, event, helper) {
        var dt=component.find('inputDate');
        dt.set('v.placeholder','[enter due date here]');
    }
})
```

In a Locker-Service enabled enviroment, this works if you place the component in community template as root component.

But if you place this in another component as sub-component (nested component), it gives out an error that says:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'placeholder' of component 'markup://ui:inputDate {383:2;a} {inputDate}' is not visible to 'markup://c:INPUTDATE {381:2;a}'.
Failing descriptor: {markup://c:INPUTDATE}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you happen to have any other element with aura:id `inputDate` may be in parent component? Or just try to change the aura:id to something else, inputDate being a reserved keyword.

Comment: thanks for the comment, and tried your suggestion. though it made no difference.

Comment: there is no attribute like `placholder` in `ui:inputdate` component. refer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm

Comment: @vignesh, yes i know. it more of a workaround. but why the first one works in the first place?

Comment: I tried your code. Its not working when used as nested component, however I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: the error isn't visible. you have to inspect the document, and find "auraErrorMessage" div. The error is there.